# Head customization won't show in quick change stations

Tags: borderlands-2

I bought the 'Pretty in Punk' head customization in the Torgue machine in the DLC. I opened my inventory and selected it to unlock it. It showed that it did, so when I went to a quick change station to use it, it didn't show in the list. Any reason why this would be happening? (I'm on the Steam PC version if it helps.)

Comment: This might be obvious, but are you playing as the character the head is for?

Answer (score 1):

First you must read the requirements.. If the head shows to be for another character and the character you have isn't the same it will only be available for the character you unlocked.. Try looking at the other vault hunters and look at witch one has it